# Swiching webhosting company & database erros

Tags: web-hosting, a-record

Well here comes the situation.

I used to have CompanyA for webhosting. (The hosting plan was a shared one).
I decided to change the hosting provider and transfer my website to CompanyB, (exclusive IP).

The issue that i face is that my webpage is now displayed in two different IP addresses.
So i decided to turn-off the website served by the CompanyA.

Now the problem is that my database driven website, served by CompanyB, is not driven anymore, although i have added the **A record** mssql.mywebsite.com with the ipaddress of the database. (The database is served by dedicated db's server).

So, what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You mention using a CNAME pointing at the database's IP address. If the DNS record is truly pointing at an IP address instead of another name, you should use an A record.

Comment: Sorry about mistyping. The records is A.

Answer (score 1):

When you moved from CompanyA to CompanyB, did you move your database with it? If you did, and it's running and everything, make sure that you updated your application's configuration to point to the new host at CompanyA.

If you originally configured it with the IP address instead of domain name, that would explain the symptoms.

Comment: No i did not move the database, while swiching from CompanyA to B. The database is hosted in different IP Address

Comment: Is the database hosted with company A?

Comment: Yes the database is hosted with company A

Comment: I think that's your problem. Either company A turned off your database, or your database is set to let you log in from a specific address (or address block), and you've changed to Company B. Talk to Company A and see what the specific issue is.

Comment: It definitely sounds like this is the source of the problem in one way or another.  If the database is accessible, it could also be something like the database permissions that the app uses not allowing for the remote connection (ie, MySQL's user@host).

Comment: Also, for what it's worth.  Using mysql (or anything else, for that matter) to connect back to a remote server across a WAN link is rarely encrypted, and is not really advisable.  I'd set up an OpenVPN tunnel if i really had to do it that way.